# Looping url from csv file for scrape html with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm learning to use python to scrape websites (online store)
I'm create a blocke code to scrape a website, where the url to scrape is in the CSV file that I will load to scrape.
However, after running the repetition can only work once in one of the lines does not reach the end of the url in the CSV and does not continue to the next URL.

```
disc_information = html.find('div', class_='alert alert-info global-promo').text.strip().strip('\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

how do I get through if an error occurs when html is not found?

the following line of code I use python, please help so that the looping scrape runs to the end of the url list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import pandas


with open('Url Torch.csv','rt') as f:
  data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  for row in data:
      URL_GO = row[2]

def variable_Scrape(url):
    try:
        cookies = dict(cookie="............")
        request = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
        html = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
        title = html.find('div', class_='title').text.strip().strip('\n')
        desc = html.find('div', class_='content').text
        link = html.find_all('img', class_='lazyload slide-item owl-lazy')
        normal_price = html.find('div', class_='amount public').text.strip().strip('\n')
        disc_information = html.find('div', class_='alert alert-info global-promo').text.strip().strip('\n')

    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
        #ConnectionAbortedError
        return False
    else:
        print(title)
        #print(desc)
        #print(link)
    finally:
        print(title)
        print(desc)
        print(link)
        print('Finally.....')
variable_Scrape(URL_GO)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the **variable_Scrape(URL_GO)** method inside the **for-loop** and make sure you declare the method before it uses.